# React functions not happening in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem I'm having is that this set of code NEEDS to happen in order. It is all packaged inside a component that is updating every second.

Here is what I want to happen when the component mounts:

Step 1: On load, retrieve the last known timestamp stored in local storage and subtract it by `new Date() /1000` then console log the answer.

Step 2: retrieve all data from local storage and update state (this includes the timestamp), continuing this process every second.

As it stands in my code, step 2 is happening first.

Here's a video of the app I'm working with and the component that's updating every second to provide context to my issue. I highlight my console log being 0. This is the issue I want to fix. I need the console log to not give me 0, but the current timestamp - the previous timestamp. This is so if a user using my app goes offline and comes back, it counts the time they were gone.:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0tOZhHfio4

Here's my current code:

```
  const exampleComponent = () => {

  const d = new Date() /1000
  
  const timeStamp = () => {
    return Math.round(d)
  }

  const idler = () => {
    return timeStamp() - Lockr.get('timeStamp')
  }
  
  window.onload = (event) => {
     console.log(idler())
  }
 saveLockr(state)

    useEffect(() => {
const timer = setInterval(() => {
setState((state) => ({
  minions: state.minions,
  counter: state.counter + state.minions + (state.minionSupervisors*3) + (state.minionManagers * 9) + 
  (state.grandmas * 18) + 
  (state.dads * 36) + 
  (state.aliens * 72) +
  (state.angels * 144),
  minionSupervisors: state.minionSupervisors,
  minionManagers: state.minionManagers,
  grandmas: state.grandmas,
  dads: state.dads,
  aliens: state.aliens,
  angels: state.angels,
}));
  }, 1000);
  
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line
},[]);
}
```

The SaveLockr hook code:

```
 const saveLockr = (state) => {
  const d = new Date() /1000
  
  const timeStamp = () => {
    return Math.round(d)
  }

  Lockr.set("counter", state.counter);
  Lockr.set("minions", state.minions);
  Lockr.set("minionSupervisors", state.minionSupervisors);
  Lockr.set("minionManagers", state.minionManagers);
  Lockr.set("grandmas", state.grandmas);
  Lockr.set("dads", state.dads);
  Lockr.set("aliens", state.aliens);
  Lockr.set("angels", state.angels);
  Lockr.set('timeStamp', timeStamp())
  
};
```

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We've not enough context here if you are using React. Please don't re-add the `reactjs` tag until you add ***valid*** react code to your question.

Comment: added the useeffect as well thats causing the updates

Comment: Lockr stuff is also a side effect. Put them into a useEffect, too.

Comment: Just about all the code you had in your original edit belongs in an `useEffect` hook, to be called when the component mounts, otherwise it's all unintentional side-effects. Javascript is synchronous, but has asynchronous functionality. I suspect something with the lockr/localStorage is processing asynchronously, so you'll need to write your logic to handle this in a synchronous manner, i.e. `await` any asynchronous functions to complete before moving on. The `window.onLoad` here likely also isn't helping you.

Comment: I can't, if I do it stops updating every second from the useEffect which is desired. I just want to be able to do a Lockr.get() function before the Lockr.set() function triggers when I load the page. I'll include a video of my app to better explain my conundrum

Comment: Added a video of not just my issue, but also trying to put things in a useEffect. I'm sorry if my explanations have been poop, I'm new to this whole thing so I hope the video helps.

Comment: Well, from what I can gather from your code snippet and your video it appear you are updating local component state on a 1 second interval and updating localStorage as a side-effect (anti-pattern). What is `saveLocker`? Again, if you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can see what your code is really trying to do and make better suggestions. Can you do this and include step-by-step what you want to happen when this component mounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. I don't know exactly what you are doing, but you have to know that Javascript is an asynchronous programming language. That means that stuff doesn't happen in order. If a function takes time, Javascript will go onto the next function. It won't wait for the first function to finish to then go to the second function. This makes Javascript very efficient but adds a little more difficulties to the user. There are a few ways to go around this. I have linked articles to three methods.

Callbacks:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp

Promises:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

Async/Await:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

You can choose whichever you like depending on your circumstances. Also there is something wrong with your code on the last line.
`Lockr.set('timeStamp', timeStamp());`
You are passing in the timestamp function. When you do this remove the `()` from the `timestamp`. Anyways, I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 
getting rid of the () from timestamp actually broke my code and returned undefined because its not being invoked within the Lockr.set() function. 
I added more to my OP while you were making your reply(i think)
which of these methods you linked should I try? So far I tried async and got no dice

Comment: LocalStorage access is not async and Lockr also doesn't mention anything about being async. This should not be an issue.

Comment: I might be placing my async in the wrong place. I tried googling for more info on using async await in a useEffect so maybe I could do everything in the `setInterval()` function, but I always got errors with whatever I tried. Where should I place async and await?

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT I DID IT I DID IT!

Here's the answer to my problems:

useEffects! Let's go more in depth though.
instead of `window.onload` to run my code when the component mounts, we use

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(idler())
  },[])
```

the `[]` gives us an exit so that the useEffect doesn't trigger every time the component updates.
We still have to clean up my `saveLockr(state)` hook though. Let's toss that in a useEffect as well!

```
useEffect(() => {
    saveLockr(state);
  })
```

This time there's no `[]` so that it will save state every time my component updates.

useEffects keep everything happening in order so I can get my desired results!

The confusion was caused by my lack of understanding on what the `[]` even do in a useEffect so I ended up not using it, or using it incorrectly in my question.